# How to Update Form submission Information in sitecore 9?

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-api, sitecore-forms

User Submit the Form data, insert those values by default in to "[ExperienceForms].[sitecore_forms_storage].[FieldData]" Table. how can we edit using API or Power Shell script?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That data is never supposed to be changed. It's what user entered in the form, plus a random guid for `FormEntryId` - it's a unique identifier of that particular form entry (the one you highlighted in your screenshot). Its value has no meaning - it's just a reference so form reports and user related form data can be generated properly. It's like ID of Sitecore item - you don't really care what its value is, as long as all the references are correct.

So to answer your question, there is no way of changing it via Sitecore API or via Sitecore Powershell Extensions.

You could change the values in database using SQL script, but that would most probably break all the reports.

Comment: Marek, thank you for response. I marked "FormEntryId" just for reference, actually i need to update Field name "Status" in above screen shot. so based on your answer only way to update using Sql script? is that correct?

Comment: changing "value" using sql script how break the reports ? we are not updating any ID information.Ex: Change value from "Pending" to "Success".

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other option than SQL script. Changing "Value" column values won't break the reports. However for some of them it may be necessary to rebuild reporting database potentially. Best try with test for in your local environment first.